# How can I install Erlang on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) without internet connection?

Tags: linux, erlang, suse

I want to install Erlang on this Suse 11 which isn't able to access internet. I found the link in Suse web site but it seems the client need the internet to access it.

Is there binary build I can download and install?

Comment: Requests for off-site links are generally off-topic on StackExchange sites. In any case, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: SLES 11 Erlang http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/erlang/ →  SP1,  SP2,  SP3,  SP4 : ~140 packages. Download the packages →copy to an usb-stick .

Comment: Thanks for the info, Knud. It leads me to something eventually works after I got the internet connection :   zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:erlang:Factory/SLE_11_SP3/devel:languages:erlang:Factory.repo [newline]
zypper refresh [newline]
zypper install erlang [newline]    Hope it'll help someone.